# Extracting, or adding to, original data values from randomForest model in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a randomForest model generated from a dataset in R.  I do not have the original data used to create that model.  Ultimately, what I'd like to do is add to the original dataset used to create that model to increase the sample size in that model.

I can think of two ways to do that.  1)  Directly add data to the original model.  I tried that via ?update, but it doesn't appear to work the way I think it does.  The following code makes a really simple random forest, then tries to update the formula w/ additional x and y data, but looking at the str results it's apparent that nothing is added:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 2:11
z <- 3:12
mod <- randomForest(z~x+y)
str(mod)

test <- cbind(runif(100,0,10),runif(100,0,10),runif(100,100,1000))
colnames(test) <- c("x","y","z")

mod2 <- update(mod,.~., test)
str(mod2)
```

From the documentation, it appears you need the original data to update?

2)  Get the original data out of the model object somehow.  This is less desirable, but if I did this I could simply append data to the original data and reconstruct the model.  The randomforest object has the original response variable z via (mod$y) but doesn't, I don't believe, have the original x and y values.  It does, however, have the entire forest.

I apologize if this isn't clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I can't execute your code; from which package does the function `randomForest` come?

Comment: From a quick look, I don't think either option will work.  `update` only updates the call, i.e. the formula, not the data -- it needs the original data and will re-fit to this data. If you remove your original x, y, and z objects you'll see that the `update` function fails.  And for option 2, the randomForest object does not contain the original data.

Comment: The library is randomForest.

Comment: Thanks for the response jmuhlenkamp.  I agree that it doesn't seem possible, at least in a straightforward manner.  It's just odd that the original response variables are in the randomforest model object, and the entire forest, but not the original predictors (as it appears to be the case)...  or that with the whole forest, one couldn't update somehow with a new set of x, y, and z.  Too bad, perhaps there's a more clever way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question (which is how I stumbled on this post), and I ended up finding the answer.

As mentioned by @jmuhlenkamp, the randomForest object does not contain the original data. But, you can always extract the data from the call used to create the object.

Here's an example:

```
require(randomForest)
data(iris)
rf = randomForest(Species~., data=iris)
data_name = getCall(rf)$data
iris_again = eval(data_name)
```

Then you can update the formula using `update` as needed, then supply a new (modified in your case) dataset.